# telethon fails on python on GAE platform

Tags: telethon

I would appreciate if somebody could shine a light on this, I try to setup a simple telegram bot to be run on Python on Google App Engine with telethon libarary, but failed. Was this approach workable ?

after gcloud app deploy, I receive the Internal Server Error from browser.
the problem does not happen if I remarked the following line:

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

### main.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import datetime
import time
import asyncio

from telethon import  TelegramClient, events, sync

app = Flask(__name__)

api_id = xxxxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
phone = '+xxxxxxxxxxxx'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    reqaction = request.args.get('action', 'connect')
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

below is the logging:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 95, in hello
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) ;
  File "lib/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 230, in __init__
    self._loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

Many thanks in advance for your giude and help :)

Comment: flask uses threads while telethon is an async library. you should use something like aiohttp or quart instead. https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/

Comment: thx painor for pointing the route. i have give up GApps on doing that. and switch to other platform.